# Filter , group by and count in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataset

A TSV file contains some user event data :

```
user_uid category event_type
"11"      "like"   "post"
"33"      "share"  "status"
"11"      "like"   "post"
"42"      "share"  "post"
```

what is the best way to get the number of `post` events for each category and for each user_id?

we should show the following output:

```
user_uid category count
"11"     "like"    2
"42"     "share"   1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clean up any trailing whitespace so that things group properly. Filter your `DataFrame`, and then apply `groupby` + `size`

```
df['category'] = df.category.str.strip()
df['user_uid'] = df.user_uid.str.strip()
df[df.event_type == 'post'].groupby(['user_uid', 'category']).size()
```

Output:

```
user_uid  category
11        like        2
42        share       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Did you try it ? because the result not as you wrote in your answer .

Comment: @AhmedGamal Yes, `df = pd.read_clipboard()` followed by my code gave me that answer. How is your answer different?

Comment: the result incorrect as your code does not print 2 for category like and user_uid 11
it prints three lines with count 1 for every line

Comment: @AhmedGamal Can you show me the output of `print(df.category.unique())`

Comment: ['like   ' 'share    ' 'like      ' 'share     ']

Comment: I just ran this on my end, and it worked as described. I assume there is an issue on the OP's end.

Comment: The solution should work as expected. Was curious so tried out myself and it does give the expected result `df=pd.DataFrame({'user_uid':['11','22','11','42'],'category':["like","share","like","share"],'event_type':["post","status","post","post"]})
df[df.event_type == 'post'].groupby(['user_uid', 'category']).size()`

Comment: @AhmedGamal I'm not sure how that's the output of `unique` because that by definition has to de-duplicate the array, and those values look duplicated. But it seems like you have issues with surrounding whitespace. Try `df['category'] = df.category.str.strip()` for both the `category` and `user_id` variables.

Comment: I got it i think the categories has some spaces , now it works